# How to prove that unnormalized neg entropy is strongly convex with respect to the $1$-norm?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The unnormalized negative entropy of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ is
$$
g(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_i (x_i \log(x_i) - x_i)
$$
it is stated that $g(\mathbf{x})$ is strongly convex with respect to 1-norm, i.e.
$$
\sum_i\left(x_i \log\left(\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right) + y_i - x_i\right) \geq \frac{\lambda}{2} \left(\sum_i |x_i - y_i|\right)^2
$$
for a certain $\lambda > 0$. I tried and looked around, but couldn't establish this inequality.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That inequality is clearly false.  The right side grows quadratically as $x_1 \to \infty$, the left side does not.

Comment: When I tried to prove this I found it might be provable if $\mathbf{1}^\top \mathbf{x} \leq 1$, but the definition of unnormalized entropy seems not asking this.

Answer (score 0):

This strong convexity property is true when restricted to $\{x > 0 : \|x\|_{1} \leq B\}$ for some constant $B$ (then $\lambda$ will depend on $B$).

For a proof of the above fact, see [Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality).